# How can I change the predefined color in Android with xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-styles

Its not so long since I started to program in Android Studio. I was wondering why everything that I'm adding (like button, the actionBar...) has already a Lilac predefined color and how I can change this color. When I tried to change the color of the button in xml of my activity nothing happened.

```
android:background="@color/teal_200"
```

Can you help me please to know where I can change this default color and why the

> android:background="@color/teal_200"

didn't worked?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements will likely be in an activity and that activity will have a theme, which you can check by looking at the `android:theme` of the activity (or the application, if the activity doesn't have one) in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

If you've started a new project from a template, this theme will likely be in `res/values/themes.xml` and it will define colours that will be used wherever that theme is applied.

Different elements take different colours from the theme and you need to check the documentation for each one to understand where their colours come from and how to change them.

For example, if you're using a contained MaterialButton, its documentation is [here](https://material.io/components/buttons/android). There you can see that it takes its background colour from the `colorPrimary` of the theme by default and this can be overridden by setting the `app:backgroundTint` of the button. Therefore, if you wanted to change the colour of all the contained buttons in activities that use that theme, you'd need to change the `colorPrimary` of the theme. You could also change the colour of individual buttons by setting the `app:backgroundTint` of each button.

Note that several UI elements also use the colours set in the theme (like `colorPrimary`) and they'll change if you change those values. There's more info about what the colours in the theme are used for [here](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color), [here](https://material.io/blog/android-material-theme-color) and [here](https://material.io/design/color/applying-color-to-ui.html#buttons-chips-and-selection-controls) and more general info about themes and styles [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes).

Answer (score 0):

please change in colors.xml in your resource file

Answer (score -1):

Open values -> colors.xml and add the color you want and set it in the layout XML file

Comment: The question is related to dynamic theming